# Visual Studio equivalent to Eclipse keyboard shortcut Alt Shift L

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I just did a few years of Java and I'm now back in the C# world. I'm actually happy to be back in Visual Studio except for one thing.

The Eclipse shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> really grew on me and I can't find an equivalent in Visual Studio to extract local when the cursor is on a method.

Anyone knows the equivalent in Visual Studio please?

Comment: You mean you want to create a local variable holding the result of calling the method...?

Comment: What does ALT SHIFT L do, for those of us who don't use Eclipse?

Comment: A demonstration of 'extract local' in Eclipse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YkAKK5XQ5w

Comment: And for the text crowd:  ALT SHIFT L extracts selected code to a new local variable -  ALT SHIFT M extracts a new method from selected code - if you don't miss them you don't know what you're missing ;)

Answer (score 4):

There's no native Visual Studio 2010 refactoring command for 'extract local', as Eclipse has.

The closest you'd get is the 'Extract Constant', which isn't by default bound to a keyboard shortcut. To do this, you have to highlight the entire string, including the double-quote `"` delimiters.

[image: extract constant]

You could explore third party IDE addons like CodeRush or ReSharper for more functionality.

Comment: I'm gonna go investigate those add-ons right now. I'll reply w/ my findings. Thanks.

Comment: I guess Visual Studio definitely is not Eclipse... Forgot you had to pay for IDE add-ons for a while... back to reality! From the documentation ReSharper seems to be the right tool to do that, but I'm not gonna pay for it.

Comment: @Lance: it may not be all pay, unsure if there are any suitable in here ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Visual_Studio_add-ins

Comment: Thanks for the list, I'll take a look. I like it :) !

Answer (score 1):

TO get 'Extract Constant' you need to install 'PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010' from:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/

Answer (score 1):

For MSVS 2013 you can download [Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) to get *Extract Constant* - features also *Ctrl + Click to Peek Definition* (customizable to *Go* to definition as in all other IDEs I used) and it is free !

To install go to *Tools > Extensions and Updates...* then *Online*

Answer (score -1):

With extension VAssisX, you can bind keys to this: VAssisX.RefactorIntroduceVariable

And I think this does what you want.